# If a language has several dialects, which dialect should I learn?

Tags: beneficial-effects, detrimental-effects, learning-order

Most language-learning resources seem to focus on dialects spoken in a capital city or some similar commercial hub.  Is this always the best starting point, or are there other factors that should be taken into consideration that may mean other dialects would be a more suitable focus? Does anyone know of any languages where learning the dialect of the capital should actually be avoided initially?

Comment: Your questions seems to be almost entirely opinion-based; you should learn whichever dialect is relevant to your life. If you're moving to Madrid, learn Castilian Spanish. If you're moving to Mexico, learn Latin American Spanish. Unfortunately, we simply can't answer this question for you.

Comment: "Does anyone know of any languages where learning the dialect of the capital should actually be avoided initially?" -- The only reason that I could imagine you **wouldn't** want to learn the "dialect of the capital" is if another dialect is supposedly easier for beginners to learn. These are just my thoughts, though, feel free to listen to what the rest of the community has to say :)

Comment: What about reformulating the question as "Are there any languages where one should initially not learn the dialect of the capital because it differs considerably from the standard language?". (Of course, it is hard to define "considerably".)

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on your goals. If you are going to move to a particular location where the dialect you want to study is spoken (or if you have some other incentive to study that location's dialect), you should probably do it.

If you want to be more versatile and be able to talk with people from basically anywhere, then it's best that you choose a more neutral variety. If you prefer to learn a standard dialect and your target language has several "standard" dialects (as it is the case for French, German or English), choose whichever dialect that you like best, or that you feel will be most useful given the use you'll make of it.

And even if your goals change later down the road (e.g. if you suddenly get to work a lot more with people with another dialect than the one you started with), you will probably be able to either adjust your dialect or just keep the same while still making yourself understood.

Answer (score 7):

There is no thing like **"should"** in the context of learning foreign languages.

Each dialect has its own beauty/usefulness, otherwise they were extinct by now.

However, learning **the standard, official dialect** of a language seems to be the best practice for the beginner Language Learner (LL). Note that the *official* dialect is not the same thing as the *"most popular language of the country's capital"*. One vivid example is German language, as another answer suggests.

This is why the official dialect is better for a beginner LL, comparing to other dialects of the same language:

- there are more learning materials available;
- most citizens of the target country know the official dialect (in addition to their local one);
- hence, a LL may have more partners to practice or communicate with;

Once the LL is more or less familiar with the official dialect, their interest to some other dialect of the same language may naturally appear.

Comment: "There is no thing like 'should' in the context of learning foreign languages." I.e. you are saying there is no thing like "thou shalt" either ;-D I would just like to add one point to your answer: Often all the available materials for learning a country's regional dialect are in that countries standard language, so if you are not actually living in that very region and learning by immersion then you will have to first learn the standard language anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Thou shalt **NOT** learn Swabian, the dialect spoken in Berlin, the capital of Germany.

---

EDIT: This is answer has two sides. The serious side is that the [Standard German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German) in Germany is not identical with any German regional dialect (even though there is a "long-standing de facto standard *pronunciation*" which "is similar to the formal German spoken in and around Hanover"). Not only that, but as you can see in the same Wikipedia article, there is actually not only one version of Standard German, but three: "German Standard German, Swiss Standard German and Austrian Standard German" (the first being the Standard German for [the Federal Republic of] Germany).

The not so serious side of the answer is that it's very tongue in cheek - I was trying to make my fellow Germans smile (I hope I didn't offend anyone). The pun being 1) that the traditional dialect of Berlin is not Swabian but [Berlinerisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlinerisch_dialect) and 2) that there have been [tensions](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/shoot-swabians-berlin-berates-its-bourgeois-invaders-8439039.html) between some of the local populace and the Swabians (Schwaben) who came to Berlin after the German unification (the term 'Schwaben' also "[being used as a Synonym for all sorts of well-to-do west-German immigrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwabenhass)").

Comment: Why people should not learn this specific dialect? What makes it not advisable?

Comment: Standard German speakers probably would not understand a lot of it, as it is quite different. See [*Swabian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabian_German)

Comment: @Vanege Swabian is one of the most disliked dialects in Germany. But I would still stick to Standard German if I did not live in Swabia.

Comment: Yes, apart from my pun on inner-German tensions this was the idea:
1) The regional dialect of the capital is not always the standard language of a country (example: Germany)
2) Unless you have a personal reason (e.g. living in or being interested in the culture of a specific region, having relatives in or from that region, just liking the sound of that specific dialect etc.) do not learn a dialect--not even the dialect of the capital--but rather the standard language. See bytebuster's and Baloung's answers for some reasons why.